# How to update existing data from DB with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-hook-form

I'm creating an E-commerce like website, we upload products through the admin site.

I have `Upload.tsx` file like so:

```
...
import FormDetails from '@components/FormDetails';

const Upload: React.FC = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, unregister, watch, setValue } =
    useForm<UploadFormState>();
  const watchPacksOrWholesale = watch('packsOrWholesale');

  const [uploadLoading, setUploadLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState<string>('');
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState<number>(0);
  const [createdAt, setCreatedAt] = useState<Timestamp | null>(null);

  const saveProduct = useProductStore((state) => state.saveProduct);
  const isLoading = useProductStore((state) => state.isLoadingSave);

  const handleProductSubmit: SubmitHandler<UploadFormState> = (data) => {
    const newProductUpload = {
      drinkName: data.drinkName,
      description: data.description,
      category: data.category,
      price: Number(data.price),
      url,
      createdAt,
      packsOrWholesale: data.packsOrWholesale,
      packSize: data.packSize,
    };

    saveProduct(newProductUpload, reset, setFile);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Text fontSize="xl" mb={5} fontWeight="semibold">
        Upload Drinks
      </Text>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleProductSubmit)}>
        <FormDetails
          register={register}
          file={file}
          progress={progress}
          setFile={setFile}
          setProgress={setProgress}
          isRequired={true}
          unregister={unregister}
          watchPacksOrWholesale={watchPacksOrWholesale}
          setValue={setValue}
        />
        <ButtonGroup mt={4} spacing={2}>
          <Button
            size="sm"
            isLoading={uploadLoading}
            isDisabled={!file || progress === 100}
            onClick={handleProductImageUpload}
          >
            Upload Image
          </Button>
          <Button
            size="sm"
            type="submit"
            variant="solid"
            // isDisabled={!file || progress === 0}
            colorScheme="success"
            isLoading={isLoading}
          >
            Save Product
          </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Upload;
```

.....

FormDetails.tsx

```
import {
  ....
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { FileInput } from '@components/FormFields';

import { drinkCategoriesArray } from '@data/index';
import { FormDetailsProps } from '@interfaces/index';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

const FormDetails: React.FC<FormDetailsProps> = ({
 ....
}) => {
  const [isPacksOrWholesale, setIsPacksOrWholesale] = useState<boolean>(
    product?.packsOrWholesale || false
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (watchPacksOrWholesale) {
      register('packsOrWholesale', { required: true });
    } else {
      unregister('packsOrWholesale');
    }
  }, [register, unregister, watchPacksOrWholesale, isPacksOrWholesale]);

  return (
    <>
      <SimpleGrid columns={{ base: 1, sm: 2 }} spacing={6} textAlign="left">
        <FormControl>
          <FormLabel fontSize="14px">Drink name</FormLabel>
          <Input
            {...register('drinkName', { required: isRequired })}
            type={'text'}
            placeholder="Meridian"
            defaultValue={(showValue && product?.drinkName) || ''}
          />
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl>
          <FormLabel fontSize="14px">Description</FormLabel>
          <Input
            {...register('description', { required: isRequired })}
            type={'text'}
            placeholder="Meridian wine is the best"
            defaultValue={(showValue && product?.description) || ''}
          />
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl>
          <FormLabel fontSize="14px">Select Category</FormLabel>
          <Select
            {...register('category', { required: isRequired })}
            placeholder="Select category"
            defaultValue={(showValue && product?.category) || ''}
          >
            {drinkCategoriesArray.map(({ drinkCategory, drink_id }) => (
              <option key={drink_id} value={drinkCategory}>
                {drinkCategory}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl>
          <FormLabel>
            <FormLabel fontSize="14px">Select Product method</FormLabel>
            <HStack>
              <Text fontWeight={'semibold'}>Product in wholesale</Text>
              <Switch
                id="packs switch"
                {...register('packsOrWholesale')}
                colorScheme={'primary'}
                size={'sm'}
                fontWeight={'semibold'}
                defaultChecked={showValue && product?.packsOrWholesale}
                isChecked={isPacksOrWholesale}
                onChange={() => setIsPacksOrWholesale(!isPacksOrWholesale)}
              />
              <Text fontWeight={'semibold'}>Product in packs</Text>
            </HStack>
          </FormLabel>
        </FormControl>
        {isPacksOrWholesale ? (
          <FormControl>
            <FormLabel>
              <FormLabel fontSize="14px">Select pack size</FormLabel>
              <Select
                {...register('packSize', {
                  required: true,
                })}
                placeholder="Select Pack Size"
                defaultValue={(showValue && product?.packSize) || ''}
              >
                <option value="6 Packs">6 Packs</option>
                <option value="12 Packs">12 Packs</option>
              </Select>
            </FormLabel>
          </FormControl>
        ) : null}
        <FormControl mt={'3px'}>
          <FormLabel fontSize="14px">Price</FormLabel>
          <Input
            {...register('price', { required: isRequired })}
            type="number"
            placeholder="500 (in Dollars)"
            defaultValue={(showValue && product?.price) || ''}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </SimpleGrid>
       ....
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default FormDetails;

.....
```

ProductEdit.tsx

```
import FormDetails from '@components/FormDetails';

import { useProductStore } from '@store/useProductStore';

const ProductEdit = forwardRef(({ product }: ProductType, ref) => {
  const { id } = useParams<ProductParams>();
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, unregister, reset, setValue } =
    useForm<UploadFormState>();

  const watchPacksOrWholesale = watch('packsOrWholesale');

  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [uploadLoading, setUploadLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState<string>('');
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState<number>(0);
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

  const editProduct = useProductStore((state) => state.editProduct);
  const isLoading = useProductStore((state) => state.isLoadingEdit);

  const handleProductUpdate: SubmitHandler<UploadFormState> = (data) => {
    const newUpdate = {
      drinkName: data.drinkName || product?.drinkName,
      description: data.description || product?.description,
      category: data.category || product?.category,
      url: url || product?.url,
      price: Number(data.price) || Number(product?.price),
      packsOrWholesale: data.packsOrWholesale || product?.packsOrWholesale,
      packSize: data.packSize || product?.packSize,
    };

    // editProduct(id, newUpdate, onClose, setFile);
    console.log(newUpdate);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <IconButton
        aria-label="edit-button"
        size="sm"
        colorScheme="secondary"
        variant="ghost"
        onClick={onOpen}
        icon={<RiPencilLine size="18px" />}
      />
      <Modal
        isCentered
        size="lg"
        onClose={onClose}
        isOpen={isOpen}
        motionPreset="slideInBottom"
        closeOnOverlayClick={false}
      >
        <ModalOverlay backdropFilter={'blur(5px)'} />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>
            Edit Product{' '}
            <chakra.span color="success.700">{product?.drinkName}</chakra.span>?
          </ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton size="sm" />
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleProductUpdate)}>
            <ModalBody>
              <FormDetails
                register={register}
                file={file}
                progress={progress}
                setFile={setFile}
                setProgress={setProgress}
                showValue={true}
                isRequired={false}
                product={product}
                unregister={unregister}
                watchPacksOrWholesale={watchPacksOrWholesale}
                setValue={setValue}
              />
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
              <ButtonGroup mt={4} spacing={2}>
                <Button
                  isLoading={uploadLoading}
                  onClick={handleProductImageUpload}
                  isDisabled={!file || progress === 100}
                  size="sm"
                >
                  Upload Image
                </Button>
                <Button
                  size="sm"
                  type="submit"
                  variant="solid"
                  isLoading={isLoading}
                  colorScheme="success"
                >
                  Update Product
                </Button>
              </ButtonGroup>
            </ModalFooter>
          </form>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </Box>
  );
});

export default ProductEdit;
```

I have a reusable component, called `FormDetails`. I use this component to get the data from the admin input and do an upload. Alternatively, I also use it for the `ProductEdit` component.

Everything works fine, except for the fact that,

1. in the `FormDetails` component, I want to use `react-hook-form` to manage the state of what renders. i.e if `watchPacksOrWholesale` is `true`, which is linked to the `Switch` component, the `Select` component which holds the `packSize` should show.
2. The `ProductEdit` component picks the existing Product from firebase and then on editing the product using `react-hook-form` if I disable the `Switch` component the value for the PackSize should be an empty string, meaning I don't want a `packSize`. I should be able to update the product on `Firebase`.

All I'm saying is that the Switch component does not update well.